# Обработка <b-button> в bootstrap-vue

Tags: vue.js, webpack, bootstrap-vue

Пытаюсь использовать в своем проекте `bootstrap-vue`. Произвел подключение вроде все правильно, по документации. Для примера мой **app.js**:

```
require("./bootstrap");

import Vue from "vue";
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from "bootstrap-vue";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);

import Buefy from "buefy";
Vue.use(Buefy);

import "alpinejs";

import PortalVue from "portal-vue";
Vue.use(PortalVue);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import App from "./components/App.vue";

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

И вот наблюдается странная штука - все элементы на странице (из различных примеров) стилизуются, кроме `<b-button>`. Я нашел выход - сюда же в файл прописываю следующее:

```
import { BButton } from "bootstrap-vue";
Vue.component("b-button", BButton);
```

Вот только тогда и кнопки начинают стилизоваться. Увы, с `bootstrap-vue`, да и с самим `vue` знаком буквально пару дней.

**И собственно вопрос:** что не так с этим `<b-button>`? Или я что-то не так подключаю, или это так должно быть?

Answer (score -1):

**Хозяйке на заметку** :-)

Нельзя совместно использовать `bootstrap-vue` и `buefy`! Эти два фрэймворка конфликтуют. Так что, либо первый, либо второй. Как только пересоздал проект без `buefy` - все заработало как надо.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/597018)

Comment: А чем дополнять-то? Вопрос полон: не работала стилизация <b-button>. И в своем ответе я указал на найденную причину. Почему именно это происходит - это выходит за рамки моего вопроса. Причина найдена, и этого хватит.

Comment: Без объяснения почему, сложно было оценить, является ли это ответом на вопрос, или ошибочным выводом. Возможно, это временная проблема из-за бага в одном из фреймворков, или ошибка в коде.

Comment: В обоих фреймворках есть компонент <b-button>, и в каждом из фрэймворков он обрабатывается по своему. Отсюда и конфликт.

Comment: Нашел о конфликте имен на англоязычном ресурсе. Все как я и предполагал. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149987/buefy-boostrapvue-namespace-conflict